# Trocar a execução da função onchange da tag select para uma função onclick em um botão

Tags: javascript

No código abaixo a função é executada no evento `onchange="timesquare(this)"` da tag select. Como substituir esse evento por um evento onclick em um botão `<button onclick="???????????;">Converter</button>`

```js
function timesquare(s) {
var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].id);
var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;
 
  if (convert < 60) {
 document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
 return;
  }
 
  switch(optionsTime){
 case "minutes":
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
  break;
 case "hours":
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
  break;
 
 default:
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
  break;
  } 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
<br>
<select onchange="timesquare(this)" id="optionsTime">
<option></option>
 <option id="minutes">Minutos</option>
 <option id="hours">Horas</option>
 <option id="teste">Teste</option>
</select>
<br>
<span id="resultTime"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer da seguinte maneira exemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
<br>
<button id="converter">Converter</button>
<select id="optionsTime">
<option></option>
    <option id="minutes">Minutos</option>
    <option id="hours">Horas</option>
    <option id="teste">Teste</option>
</select>
<br>
<span id="resultTime"></span>
```

no javascript só capturas o evento **onclick** exemplo:

```
document.getElementById("converter").onclick = function() {
    timesquare(document.getElementById("optionsTime"));

};
```

para implementares esta solução baste removeres o atributo **onclick** do select, alterares o Html acima e o javascript ficara com este aspecto:

```
document.getElementById("converter").onclick = function() {
    timesquare(document.getElementById("optionsTime"));
};

function timesquare(s) {

var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].id);
var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;

  if (convert < 60) {
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
    return;
  }

  switch(optionsTime){
    case "minutes":
        document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
        break;
    case "hours":
        document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
        break;

    default:
        document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
        break;
  } 
}
```

tens aqui o exemplo online a funcionar 
https://jsfiddle.net/95eont96/

Comment: basta alterares o HTML para o da resposta e adicionar o javascript que mencionei.

Comment: resposta editada

Comment: já esta tudo okay ? acontece ^^, na paz estamos cá para ajudar no que for preciso!

Answer (score 0):

Para responder literalmente ao perguntado pode colocar no `onclick` no `<button>` e chamar mesma função passando em vez de `this` o elemento correspondente. Como agora está noutra etiqueta o `this` já não se aplica e temos que ir buscar o elemento com o `getElementById`:

```
<button onclick="timesquare(document.getElementById('optionsTime'));">Converter</button>
```

O que ficaria assim:

```js
function timesquare(s) {
var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].id);
var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;
 
  if (convert < 60) {
 document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
 return;
  }
 
  switch(optionsTime){
 case "minutes":
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
  break;
 case "hours":
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
  break;
 
 default:
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
  break;
  } 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
<br>
<select id="optionsTime"> <!-- sem o onchange aqui para ser perceber melhor-->
    <option></option>
 <option id="minutes">Minutos</option>
 <option id="hours">Horas</option>
 <option id="teste">Teste</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="timesquare(document.getElementById('optionsTime'));">Converter</button>
<span id="resultTime"></span>
```

Melhor no entanto seria fazer como o 13dev fez e atribuir o `onclick` diretamente pelo javascript.

Comment: Já que vc indica a resposta do 13dev vou escolher a dele como aceita :) pra vc +1 hehe

Comment: É de facto o mais correto, apenas respondi para ser literal com a pergunta, e complementar com a forma que estava a visualizar a chamada julgo eu. Eu também lhe dei o meu +1.